# Do Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that God equips humans today with the gift of prophecy?

Tags: biblical-basis, jehovahs-witnesses, prophecy, spiritual-gifts

On a number of occasions, God revealed information about future events that were to take place by giving humans the gift of prophecy. Do Jehovah’s Witnesses believe God still does this today, or has that means of communication ceased to be used?

Answer (score 4):

No Jehovah’s Witnesses do not believe that the gift of prophecy is given in our day.

We believe that the gifts given to early Christians served a special purpose in establishing that Gods favor had shifted away from the nation of Israel and was upon the followers of Jesus Christ the Messiah.

However those gifts like healing ,speaking in tongues, prophesying etc came to an end not long after the death of the apostles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from Insight on the Scriptures Volume 2 pp 690-694 regarding Prophecy:

> An inspired message; a revelation of divine will and purpose or the proclamation thereof. Prophecy may be an inspired moral teaching, an expression of a divine command or judgment, or a declaration of something to come. Prediction, or foretelling, is not the basic thought conveyed by the root verbs in the original languages (Heb., na·vaʼʹ; Gr., pro·phe·teuʹo); yet it forms an outstanding feature of Bible prophecy.
>
> By the outpouring of the holy spirit at Pentecost, Christians were granted such miraculous gifts as prophesying and the ability to speak in tongues they had not studied. In some (but not necessarily all) cases, the gift of prophesying produced predictions, as those of Agabus (Ac 11:27, 28; 21:8-11), enabling the Christian congregation or individuals thereof to gird for certain emergencies or trials. The canonical letters of the apostles and disciples also contain inspired forecasts of the future; these warned of the coming apostasy, told the form it would take, warned of God’s judgment and the future execution thereof, and revealed doctrinal truths not before understood or amplified and clarified those already given.
>
> However, in Paul’s first letter to the Corinthians he shows that the miraculous gifts, including that of inspired prophesying, were due to be done away with. (1Co 13:2, 8-10) The evidence is that with the death of the apostles these gifts ceased to be transmitted and thereafter passed off the Christian scene, having served their purpose. By that time, of course, the Bible canon was complete.  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200003561

It is clear that Jehovah's Witnesses do not believe God enables people to prophecy about future events, although the Bible does warn against "false prophets" in the last days.  Neither do Jehovah's Witnesses believe that other gifts of the Spirit, such as speaking in tongues or miraculous healing, have continued after the death of the apostles.